# How to replace a null value cell with some other value in python dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, where-clause

The operation is similar to MYSQL operation :

```
   UPDATE a.tract_201704 SET val_2000=0.91516427*val_2001 WHERE val_2001 IS NOT NULL AND val_2000 IS NULL.
```

I have a df of many columns in which there is a column named val_2000, If this contains a null value, then I want to replace this value with 0.91516427*val_2001 (scalar multiplication with the next cell).

Code so far : (val_2000 has either 100 or None)

```
    df = pd.read_csv("singleDataFile_header.csv")

    df_val2001_null = (df[df['val_2000'] != '100.000000000000']['val_2001'])
    df_val2000_null = (df[df['val_2000'] != '100.000000000000']['val_2000'])
    df_val2000_null = 0.91516427*df_val2001_null
```

But how to put this values from df_val2000_null back to original df wherever there are None values in df[val_2000] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'val_2000':[np.nan,2,3],
                   'val_2001':[4,5,6]})

print (df)
   val_2000  val_2001
0       NaN         4
1       2.0         5
2       3.0         6

df['val_2000'] = df['val_2000'].combine_first(0.91516427 * df['val_2001'])
print (df)
   val_2000  val_2001
0  3.660657         4
1  2.000000         5
2  3.000000         6
```

EDIT:

Possible problem is `nan` are strings, not `NaN` or in data are some invalid strings.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'val_2000':['nan',100,'gggg'],
                   'val_2001':[1,1,1]})

print (df)
  val_2000  val_2001
0      nan         1
1      100         1
2     gggg         1

df['val_2000'] = pd.to_numeric(df['val_2000'], errors='coerce')
print (df)
   val_2000  val_2001
0       NaN         1
1     100.0         1
2       NaN         1

df['val_2000'] = df['val_2000'].combine_first(0.91516427 * df['val_2001'])
print (df)
     val_2000  val_2001
0    0.915164         1
1  100.000000         1
2    0.915164         1
```

If only `nan`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'val_2000':['nan',100,100],
                   'val_2001':[1,1,1]})

print (df)
  val_2000  val_2001
0      nan         1
1      100         1
2      100         1

df['val_2000'] = df['val_2000'].astype(float)
print (df)
   val_2000  val_2001
0       NaN         1
1     100.0         1
2     100.0         1
```

Comment: df['val_2000'].update(0.91516427 * df['val_2001']) can it update with a where clause?

Comment: combine_first will edit val_2000 only if there is a NULL/NONE value is it?

Comment: Yes, exactly. values `2,3` are not changed.

Comment: and if check `print (0.91516427 * 4)` it is `3.66065708`

Comment: @Viv `df.val_2000.combine_first(df.val_2001 * .915)` combines these two objects taking the values from the first object first if it exists.  Then it cascades to the second object.  "Exist" means that there is a valid value for the specific index.  A null value at a particular index qualifies as not existing and will cascade to the second object.

Comment: @piRSquared - Thank you.

Comment: Good night, very late ;)

Comment: No, I think there is problem with strings saved as numeric. Check last edit.

Answer (score 2):

`fillna` is what you're looking for: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html

```
df.loc[:, 'val_2000'] = df.val_2000.fillna(0.91516427 * df.val_2001)
```

Comment: This is not updating the original df? I can still see them as blank